# How can I pass query variables to my query in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am trying to get the info on my API from GraphCMS but I am not sure how to make this possible.

I have not tried anything yet since I am not sure how can I add a variable to my query on my React app.

```
const NewsQuery = gql'
  query contentView_b0488406c55f4bf5a28ceb86138c948c($first: Int, $skip: Int, $where: PostWhereInput, $orderBy: PostOrderByInput) {
  contentView_content_b0488406c55f4bf5a28ceb86138c948c: postsConnection(first: $first, skip: $skip, where: $where, orderBy: $orderBy) {
    edges {
      node {
        status
        updatedAt
        createdAt
        id
        title
        slug
        category
        preview
        body
        author
        date
      }
    }
  }
}
' // (change the ' for a tilde)
```

And this is the query variable:
`{"first":25,"skip":0,"orderBy":null,"where":{"AND":[]}}`

I expect to fetch all the data on my API so I can render it into my app. I am using Apollo Client.

Comment: it all depends on what client library you're using on your react native app

Comment: @Ezekiel sorry, forgot to include. I am using Apollo client.

Comment: `const  {loading, error, data} = useQuery(NewsQuery, {variables: {"first":25,"skip":0,"orderBy":null,"where":{"AND":[]}}})` inside your functional component